# Error when trying to create envelope using createEnvelope()

Tags: docusignapi

So, the first thing I did was download the Quickstart example for PHP. I followed the examples there, and now, when trying to use the `createEnvelope()` method for an `EnvelopsApi` object I get an error. This is how my code looks right now

```
if (isset($response)) {
        $access_token = $response[0]['access_token'];
        // retrieve our API account Id
        $info = $apiClient->getUserInfo($access_token);
        $account_id = $info[0]["accounts"][0]["account_id"];

        // Instantiate the API client again with the default header set to the access token
        $config->setHost(config('api_url'));
        $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $access_token);
        $apiClient = new ApiClient($config);

        # 1. Create the envelope request object
        $envelope_definition = $this->make_envelope();
        $envelope_api = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);

        # 2. call Envelopes::create API method
        # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        try {
            $results = $envelope_api->createEnvelope($account_id, $envelope_definition);
        } catch (ApiException $e) {
            echo $e;
            exit;
        }
```

Take in consideration that the `make_envelope()` method is actually a copy paste from the Quickstart example. I have already double check that the `$account_id` is correct. Now, the `try` is throwing an exception and this is what I get

```
DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiException: API call to /v2.1/accounts/2696...4f5f482/envelopes failed, but for an unknown reason. This could happen if you are disconnected from the network. in /var/www/html/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/Client/ApiClient.php:321    
Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/html/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/Api/EnvelopesApi.php(4251): DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient->callApi('/v2.1/accounts/...', 'POST', Array, '{"documents":[{...', Array, '\\DocuSign\\eSign...', 
    '/v2.1/accounts/...')
    #1 /var/www/html/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/Api/EnvelopesApi.php(4171): DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi->createEnvelopeWithHttpInfo('26966786-cb88-4...', Object(DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition), 
    NULL)
    #2 /var/www/html/app/Console/Commands/Docusign.php(140): DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi->createEnvelope('26966786-cb88-4...', Object(DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition))
    #3 [internal function]: App\Console\Commands\Docusign->handle()
    #4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
    #6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(95): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
    #7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(39): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))     
    #8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(596): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
    #9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(134): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
    #10 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(258): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
    #11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
    #12 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(920): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))        
    #13 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(266): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(App\Console\Commands\Docusign), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #14 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(142): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(93): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #17 /var/www/html/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Any idea what this "unknown reason" could be?

Comment: Since you mentioned the quickstart, I take it you got your code from there? did it work originally for you?

Comment: @InbarGazit well, no it didn't work. I know Quickstart examples are great, but in this case, this is literally a copy paste from the Quickstart examples and one of your endpoints is failing. Do you know where can I find information about api exceptions? I know I'm probably doing something wrong, just wanna know what is it and fix it.

Comment: If only one is failing I suggest you see if you can find any useful info in the API logs. 
Go to Preferences at the top/right and enable API logs, repeat the error, go back and download them you'll get a ZIP file with API logs, see if you can find the bad API call in it.

Answer (score 0):

The error handling from the PHP client can be a bit vague -- basically most errors you would run into regarding envelope creation are interpreted by the client as 'API call to {URL} failed." Pending on what the underlying issue, and if the call registered to your account, we may be able to see more in the backend.

When you have a moment could you send your accountId over to matt.king@docusign.com? I can have a quick look to see if there are any errors registered.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will email you as soon as posible.